# If humans evolved from predators?

Tags: internal-consistency

What if humanity didn't evolve from the Australopithecus, but evolved from carnivorous baboon-like primates instead? What would society be like?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Your question is incredibly broad, as it completely rewrites history and asks about all the possible consequences. This is a [High Concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), but questions should be about specific problems that arose while you were thinking about this topic and researching your problems. What aspects of society are you interested in the most? Have fun!

Comment: As far as I know, all primates are omnivore, with the exception of [Tarsier, insectivore](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20170505-spectral-tarsiers-are-the-worlds-only-carnivorous-primates)

Comment: We have evolved from predators. In fact, we are the apex predator on Earth, and we have been for several thousands years. If we have evolved from baboons I'd expect some cosmetic chances in appearance, but no major changes.

Comment: Society is way too broad. You should specify: a) which time period? Are we talking about the space age or the stone age? If stone age, maybe specify a region and year for example.  b) What aspect of society? People here do not like "broad concept - now build my world for me" questions. c) You should introduce us to your world. What have you planned so far? Nobody can extrapolate exactly what would've happened, you have to make up some stuff before one can answer this question constructively

Comment: Being vegan would be quite a bit harder.

Comment: I tend to think that humans thrived because they were omnivores, and therefore were able to subsist on a wider range of food sources. Civilization began when humans learned that cultivating crops would produce a lot more food than just gathering and hunting. That's a far simpler task than learning to domesticate and raise other animals for food. The pure carnivore simians were left behind because they weren't adaptable enough.

Comment: We ARE predators, lol.

Answer (score 6):

Incredibly enough, more pacific.

Predators will avoid any fight that is not beneficial for them, they know that if they get hurt there will be little chance of healing before they starve so they will avoid it. Among predators you will have relatively less conflict than you see in most prey species.

Wolves for example rarely fight among themselves despite what popular culture says, most conflict will occur because of a roaming lone wolf or because some external pressure forced two different groups to the same area.

Predators are also much more territorial, so you will have smaller communities and by extension smaller cities. This would make wars more difficulty since no one will have the manpower to waste with wars.

Not saying that wars will be impossible, but they will be rare.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis, but keep in mind that there are no animals that conduct actual wars or build and live in cities (unless you count what some insects do). You could use that kind of argument for everything. "what if humans evolved from mushrooms?" "well, I've never heard of a mushroom driving a truck, so it is unlikely that we would've invented the truck". I'm not saying your answer is unfitting, I actually think it is the weakness of the question itself, but please be aware that those are some super strong statements

Comment: "because some external pressure forced two different groups to the same area. " "much more territorial". sound like two excellent and common reasons for war to me.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I'll reword it later with more time.

Comment: Human's didn't participate in warfare until agriculture, at which point the reward outweighed the cost of conflict. I imagine the dynamics of conflicts over resources would be different, because presumably these predator-humans would have herds of cattle or such for large-scale food production. They might be nomadic as a result. Nomads presumably have warfare, but they might be different from sedentary warfare.

Comment: It seems I don't need to edit it anymore, Ville Niemi did a good job explaining it.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between a social omnivore and a social carnivore is fairly small as far the society goes. Carnivores cannot form large herds like herbivores can, but we evolved from animals with social groups small enough for carnivores so there would be no large inherent difference.

Only predictable difference comes from the position in the food chain. Omnivores are more flexible and efficient at using available food sources than carnivores are. This would reasonably lead to lower population densities and more nomadic and dynamic life style.

Unfortunately this difference would happen fairly early in the development of civilization, around the neolithic to be specific, so instead of really telling us how the society would be different, it just tells us that the development of society diverged early and went into entirely different direction. Not very useful.

I can make some guesses, though. Human civilization was dominated by cultivation of cereals, pseudo-cereals, and potato because those are the food sources with productivity high enough to scale up with population. Fishing and pastoralism are also fairly efficient, but they do not scale sustainably. Your variant humans could start with fishing and pastoralism, but their neolithic revolution would instead of agriculture have to involve something else that allows a huge increase in population density. As with agriculture this would happen organically as a side effect of what is already done.

**Suppression of predators**

Humans have already become **the** apex predator of the world. The carnivores would pretty much become **the only** predator in theirs. They would reasonably be expected to outcompete all other predators for any prey larger than a small rodent or a frog. Sharks, crocodiles, lions, tigers, wolves... all extinct or nearly so. No cats or dogs, either. Or eagles, owls, or hawks.

**Prey management**

Human civilization has been obsessed with management of land and irrigation with resulting strict borders, erosion, salinity and so on. Carnivores would be obsessed with management of their prey. As prey are somewhat more dynamic and mobile than land, people would be aware of the need to manage prey in a sustainable and co-operative manner much earlier than in an agricultural society. With other predators going extinct this would result in pretty much every other species being managed which would have its own effects.

There is also a significant difference between the human focus on the management of things that is then extended to management of people and with carnivore focus on managing other animals that would then extend to patterns in managing people as states grow.

**Evolutionary pressure**

As the predation scaled up it would have extreme effects on the prey species. Species would survive or go extinct based on their ability to recover from predation. Smaller species with fast life cycles would outcompete the larger ones. Ectotherms would have an edge over endotherms.

This would have huge knock on effects on the environment. For example, if the fairly large grazing animals went extinct, there would be much less grasslands since the ability to sustain and even benefit from grazing is what gives grasses a huge edge over the competition. The difference would be amplified by the people not clearing up lands for cereals later on.

**Conservation of energy**

There is one implicit difference between carnivores and omnivores. Omnivores forage. That means gathering food sources that are fixed in location but are unstable in time. Predators rely on food sources that are, hopefully, more stable in time, but are mobile. This means that omnivores are constantly moving from one food source to another and looking for new food sources, Carnivores by contrast optimally move as little as possible. Longer the rest between hunts, the better. Of course carnivores need to move if their prey moves and have generally larger ranges as they need larger areas to support themselves, so they may end up moving large distances. But omnivores spend more time moving short distances. It is not a coincidence that humans are efficient at moving around and can hunt by running after prey until it collapses from exhaustion.

This of course opens a can of worms about this question : A carnivorous human probably would not have same kind of movement efficiency and mental mapping ability as humans actually have. And if it evolved from ancestors with those abilities they would outcompete it with their more efficient use of resources. So your carnivorous humans would probably not be recognizably human at all. Fortunately this is beyond the scope of the question so I'll just ignore it.

**Neolithic revolution, carnivore style**

So hunters follow the herds, then eventually the herds start dying out due to exploitation or climate shift and people need to rely on other food supplies. I can't really imagine anything other than fish being available. So population concentrates on coasts and estuaries. Sailing and coastal trade develop. First cities are born on natural harbours. Fisheries management develops as shared religious practices among the coastal people. [Aquaculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaculture) is developed as fish stocks get depleted. Much like beavers people get obsessed with creating artificial lakes and wetlands by creating dams. Civilization spreads upstream from the estuaries.

When nomadic populations recover wealth concentrates in walled cities surrounded by water. Diet is fish, crustaceans, molluscs, frogs, small rodents and birds. Red meat is traded from nomads. Life is regulated by a religion with a [Neptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune_(mythology)) equivalent as main deity. Sun, sky, or rain gods are secondary at best. They might see that water comes from the sky as rain and worry about floods messing with their dams, but water is where most of food comes from and water belongs to [Neptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hyperdimension_Neptunia_characters#Neptune)!

**And the actual answer?**

If we extrapolate few millennia from the starting point above and try to see the differences, it gets very fuzzy very soon. Some differences seem likely, but how they'd change the society would be a result of millennia of historical events. Still, some baseless guesswork follows.

The carnivores do not work the land and harvest the fruits of their labor. They sculpt the land in a shape that benefits their prey and then catch their food when they need to. They would not think about maximizing the amount of work done, they would think about maximizing the quality of work done. They would see no point in fast growth of population or economy. A consumer society would seem insane to them. Why keep constantly building new things and then throwing them away or demolishing them? Why build ugly or inefficient things when you could design it properly?

Basically they would laze around (spending minimal energy like a good predator!) take frequent naps and discuss what should be done and what would be the best way to do it. After they get a solid consensus that something needs to be done, and not a moment before, they will get up and do it in the most efficient way they know. If they spend a lot of effort on something, it is to save work later. A properly built structure requires less maintenance and lasts longer before it needs to be replaced. A beautiful design requires more work up front, but makes life more pleasant on the long run.

They won't spend lots of effort on things they are not sure, so prototyping, early testing, and iterative refinement would be popular. They'd also be fond of solutions that are low effort to adjust to new requirements or serve as many purposes as possible. They might have a strict theocracy simply because having more than one social hierarchy was too much bother. The religion would be fairly pragmatic and avoid dogmatism because... too much bother. Why spend effort on wars or schisms when few centuries of discussion will give you the **correct** solution. Meditative practices might be ubiquitous. It just *looks* like (energy efficient) napping.

A suitable credo might be : Do as little as possible, but do it the best you can. This could lead to philosophies similar to Taoism. Even if they are not an outright theocracy, it would be natural for the people to be rather spiritual and aim for harmony in everything they do.

Economy would probably be a sort of planned economy by default due to general lack of interest in accumulating personal wealth and preference for collaborative action (from prey management). On a positive side they would not see any point in maintaining centralized bureaucracies or production quotas either. Basically, while it would get much less done than a free market economy and have low growth, it would be well optimized to avoid wasted work. Which is what these people would actually care about.

Civilization would be composed of theocratic city states with basically the same religion and culture connected by water belonging to the deity they worship. There would be little interest in conflict and larger political structure would probably be a loose global coalition of equals with some being more equal than others due to various reasons.

Historically there would have been conflict and warfare with the nomadic people although with cities largely surrounded by water and nobody really caring about gathering wealth, the issues would probably be about poaching fish rather than warfare as we know it. Invention of gunpowder would give city builders an edge, with nomads eventually subjugated to protectorates or reservations. You can imagine issues similar to those of native populations subjected to European colonialism. There would probably remain ethnic, cultural and religious differences and prejudices.

One major difference would be strict population control. Historically the food supply was not capable of fast growth so fast population growth would have been disastrous. This is actually true for much of our history, so it is really a difference to society after industrialization not to our society in general. With less interest on gathering wealth, families would be started based on social status instead of being able to support one. Status would be granted by the theocracy (or simply consensus of your peers, there might be no difference for these people) for achievements recognized society.

Predators would have hunting instincts and (as with cats) a need to occasionally have bursts of physical activity that do not really make any sense. So sports would be popular. With evolution from pack hunters something involving two teams chasing a fast moving object, a ball for example, on a field of play with set rules and goals would seem likely.