# What if humans evolved from herbivores?

Tags: internal-consistency

Just like my last post, I asked [what if humans evolved from predators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/if-humans-evolved-from-predators). So I have another question, what if we also evolved from herbivorous gorilla-like primates too?

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise. Are you asking for biological or for technological or completey different implications? Also you worded it as if you were asking what would've happened if we evolved from two very different species, maybe you should reformulate that part.

Comment: This is indeed interesting. We might all be vegetarians or pacifist humans. However, as mentioned in your other question, this is just too broad - too many consequences that can be thought about to ever fit in this site. As such, please be more specific on the limitations. Do you only consider primates? As far as I know, all primates are omnivore, with the exception of [Tarsier, insectivore](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20170505-spectral-tarsiers-are-the-worlds-only-carnivorous-primates), but that also fall on carnivore category.

Comment: It's worth noting that even herbivores will eat meat if given the opportunity - deer, for example, have been observed in the wild eating meat on an opportunistic basis (as is true of most "herbivores"). Digesting meat does not require specific adaptations, like digesting cellulose does. Given that, I'm not sure what would change ... I'd say that maybe we'd have more plants in our diets, but given what bread is made of (or rice, or whatever other staple grain), maybe not.

Comment: there many humans who are herbivorous/ vegetarian from many generations none of them have evolved , so evolution is false ..

Comment: @AmruthA: Are you even serious?

Comment: In the future, please refrain from using [tag:reality-check] as the only tag on a question. Additionally, "What if?" questions are [generally discouraged](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3193/6986) on the site, especially ones as open-ended as to ask about all of society after millions of years of evolution. Voting to close as _too broad_.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition 99.99% sure..

Comment: @AmruthA: Ironclad logic. Do let us know when you have published your findings in a reputable, peer-reviewed journal — you are about to change the world!

Comment: The real issue with your question is  "What if" if you specified what adaptation would they have you might end up with something more reasonable, but even then the term herbivore is fairly broad and they ways of being an herbivore are so numerous that which adaptations these theoretical humans will have is wide open. Keep in mind as well if they evolved from something else they would not be human. You would be better off asking for a reality check about specific traits YOU think they might have.

Answer (score 12):

## A Problem With the Premise

[Some people](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/should-humans-eat-meat-excerpt/) have a beef with the idea that [humans could even evolve](http://time.com/4252373/meat-eating-veganism-evolution/) without the capacity for eating meat.

Getting fruits and vegetables is not very hard, and therefore doesn't reward smart animals very well. Those foods also require more work to sustain a creature.

Meat-eating gave use a food source which was more calorie-rich, therefore giving us a little surplus energy which we could spend on things like our brains. The further brain development may have allowed us to develop speech and other things which help humans conquer the world.

Also, one should note that eating insects does make you a meat-eater, from strict biological standpoint. Therefore gorillas, [who eat insects](https://seaworld.org/animal-info/animal-infobooks/gorilla/diet-and-eating-habits/) (where available), and orangutans, [who eat eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangutan#Diet), are meat-eating creatures. Consuming anything from [Kingdom Animalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal), except milk and honey, makes you a meat eater. (Sorry [pescetarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism), ovo-lacto vegetarians, but from a biological standpoint, you're not vegetarian!)

## The Big Differences

So we need to assume some human-like creature evolved from a herbivorous, ape-like creature. There would be some basic differences:

1. No [canines or incisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_tooth), because it wouldn't need those teeth for eating meat. The teeth it does have needs to help with eating plants, be they cooked or otherwise.
2. Altered digestive systems would also occur. It does not need the complicated meat-digesting enzymes us humans have, and may benefit from having a different digestive system. It would not be a [ruminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruminant), as apes do not possess this, but it may be taking steps in that direction.
3. Dependency on a purely herbivorous diet would have limited how far and where humans could range. This certainly prevents cultures like the [Inuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit_cuisine), who rely heavily on meat, and also limit what food sources are available to explorers, like [pemmican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pemmican).

Some attributes of humanity may not have developed, although I am not currently sure of this. Would some of them develop the mutation to [drink milk](https://youtu.be/ecZbhf96W9k) after childhood? [Would "white" be a skin color](https://youtu.be/_r4c2NT4naQ)? Limited range means these mutations may have never occurred, or never provided any particular benefit and thus prevented their proliferation.

Comment: *"No canines or incisors":* aren't gorillas a perfect counter-example? And nobody has "white" skin unless they are albinos; all humans are some shade of brown, which the YouTube video you have linked shows beautifully.

Comment: If meat-eating actually DID lead to advanced cognition, there would have to be some other environmental pressure for these herbivores. As an example foraging led to primates having excellent color vision, so there's still room for plants to pressure herbi-humans towards greater intelligence. Maybe the plants and fruits are so hard to find, hard to identify and have to be prepared in a complex way, such that the primates develop advanced faculties to survive.

Comment: @AlexP I've updated the answer to reflect the strict definition of vegetarian that I'm working with. (Vegetarian means to consume nothing from Kingdom Animalia except honey and milk.) Gorillas eat insects, orangutans eat eggs, and all other great apes eat something that is an animal. They are therefore are not herbivores, although their diets do mostly comprise of fruits and vegetables.

Comment: @FredtheJohn I feel like it wouldn't be a complete answer without mentioning the idea that meat-eating and the evolution of humans were not entirely divorced, and may be critical to our evolution in general. I'm not an expert on the theory, and I think that's an excellent area to ask another question: what evolutionary pressures would drive a true herbivore to develop human-like intelligence? Many of the "smart" animals seem to be omnivorous (like pigs) or carnivorous (like dolphins, whales, and ravens), with elephants being the exception.

Comment: You do realize that cows eat insects too, don't you? Projecting human foibles on biology is of course allowed, but rarely productive. It is a category error to speak of "vegetarian" animals; vegetarianism (and veganism etc.) are human ideologies.

Comment: @AlexP And north american deer are opportunistic carnivores. Great apes are active predators of insects, so they and therefore are not herbivores. Your counterexample isn't one. And you've obviously never seen a very pale white person; they get *white.*

Comment: I don't agree that humans couldn't evovle without meat.  I understand your argument, but I don't think it's mandatory for intellegence to evolve.  Intellect was likely driven mostly by social interactions of a pack/tribe, mostly competing for mating rights.  This could happen without meat.  The extra free time meat offered helped, but again isn't necessary.  Look at Bonobo, they are our closest relatives and while they do eat meat the vast majority of their diet is not meat.  They can survive without meat and still have all the drivers for intellect we had.

Comment: I don't agree that humans couldn't evolve without meat.  I understand your argument, but I don't think it's mandatory for intelligence to evolve.  Intellect was likely driven mostly by social interactions of a pack/tribe, mostly competing for mating rights.  This could happen without meat.  The extra free time meat offered helped, but again isn't necessary.  Look at Bonobo, they are our closest relatives and while they do eat meat the vast majority of their diet is not meat.  They can survive without meat and still have all the drivers for intellect we had.